# How do you add radio button answers to an array of user answers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I'm trying to create a user questionnaire where, similar to a quiz on BuzzFeed, a user selects their preferences and is given an answer based on how their preferences match up to a table on a database.

For example, here is one of the questions:

```
<form class="testAns" id="heightAns">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="short">-25%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="short">-10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="mid">normal
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="tall">+10%
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="tall">+25%
</form>
```

In the "values" section, I have added the description that I want the answer to be associated with.  These "values": short, tall, and mid will show up on the database, but I don't understand enough about Javascript or PHP to connect a user answer on the HTML to an entry on a database.

I think what I need to do is create a Java Script function for each question where the answer that the user selects is logged as its corresponding value.  Then, once all tests are completed, I need a PHP function that logs the user profile into the database

Answer (score 0):

You might be right, you might be wrong with your assumptions. It all depends on how exactly you want to display the questions and process the answer.

The simplest solution I would recommend so far, is not to use javascript at all and just use the form element for what it was designed: sending form data to a server.

Extend the form element with the attributes method="POST" and action="url_of_your_page processing_the_data"

Then on that php page you get the value via $_POST["answer"]. If you got that working, you might want to spice it up to your hearts content.

Comment: In $_POST["answer"], do I need to have "answer" exactly match the name of the field that I want the data to be inserted into?

If the field that I want this answer inserted into is called "Height", how can I delegate that the answer to the specific question above takes on the value "Height = *answer*" so that the database recognizes it as such?

Comment: since the name of the radio elements is "answer" you need to match that in $_POST. But you can choose whatever name you like. But getting the value in the database is quite a bit more work. A code example would help. Getting values in a database is way to generic to answer.

Comment: Alright, so I've got a database called 'Persons' on my site that has the following fields:
-Name (inserted through submit form)
-City (inserted through submit form)
-Height
-Spacing
-Width
-Weight

These last 4 are going to be the fields that a user's answers need to be inserted into.  These fields match up with corresponding fields in another table that holds the metrics of different typefaces.

Does that help?

Comment: Then it is just a matter of getting the posted values into the query, isn't it. It might just work to use the other names as names for the form field when the match exactly, but there is no way of knowing for sure. All depends on the code

Answer (score 0):

The value of the radio button should me the value which you are going to store in the database. If -25% is short and -10% is also short why add another radio button just use one

```
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="short">-10% or less
```

Same goes for tall.

Now to answer you question you can use `ajax` to submit the form to a `php` file which stores the result in `mysql` **OR** Make one Form place all the questions in the separate div tags and on submit the form will be submited to a `php` file

```
<form action='answer.php' method="POST">
<div>
Question 1 ............
<input ......
</div>
<div>
Question 2 ............
<input ......
</div>
</form>
```

The above code is just an example, you'll have to make a `php` file named `answer.php` to process your form

Comment: Using the method that you use as an example, would "value" inside the <input> tag translate to the specific database table field that I want the data to grouped into?  Or is that "name"?

I want the user's answer to the above question to be submitted into a database under the specific field "Height" with either the value "short", "mid", or "tall".

Comment: The name `attribute` is the name of the variable and `value` is the value that the variable will store. If the name of the `input` is **answer** you can access the users `input` through `$_POST['answer']` variable in the `php` file.